# Dynamic query php/ mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have some issues with a dynamic query:

```
    $cond = array();

    if (!empty($type_contrat)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.type_contrat = '$type_contrat'";
    }

    if (!empty($categorie_poste)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.cat_poste = '$categorie_poste'";
    }

    if (!empty($niveau_etudes)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.qualifications = '$niveau_etudes'";
    }

    if (!empty($experience)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.experience >= '$experience'";
    }       

    if (count($cond)) {

                $query = $mysqli->query('SELECT 
                job_offers.ref_org,
                job_offers.titre,
                job_offers.qualifications,
                job_offers.experience,
                job_offers.cat_poste,
                job_offers.type_contrat,
                job_offers.taux_occupation,
                job_offers.lieu_affectation,
                job_offers.pays,
                job_offers.url,
                job_offers.date_entered,
                job_offers.date_expire,
                organisations.ref_org,
                organisations.name_organisation
                FROM job_offers,organisations
                WHERE job_offers.ref_org = organisations.ref_org AND ');

                $query .=  implode(' AND ', $cond);
    }


    print_r($query);
```

--> result: prints only (linebreaks added for readability):

```
job_offers.type_contrat = '1' AND
job_offers.cat_poste = '3' AND
job_offers.qualifications = '2' AND
job_offers.experience >= '1'
```

and therefore no result.

Comment: did my answer fix the problem for you?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to append a string to a mysqli-result object...

Check the returnvalue of the mysqli->result() function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Since someone is keen on removing this answer; here's your solution:

```
    $cond = array();

    if (!empty($type_contrat)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.type_contrat = '$type_contrat'";
    }

    if (!empty($categorie_poste)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.cat_poste = '$categorie_poste'";
    }

    if (!empty($niveau_etudes)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.qualifications = '$niveau_etudes'";
    }

    if (!empty($experience)) {
        $cond[] = "job_offers.experience >= '$experience'";
    }       

    if (count($cond)) {

                $query = $mysqli->query('SELECT 
                job_offers.ref_org,
                job_offers.titre,
                job_offers.qualifications,
                job_offers.experience,
                job_offers.cat_poste,
                job_offers.type_contrat,
                job_offers.taux_occupation,
                job_offers.lieu_affectation,
                job_offers.pays,
                job_offers.url,
                job_offers.date_entered,
                job_offers.date_expire,
                organisations.ref_org,
                organisations.name_organisation
                FROM job_offers,organisations
                WHERE job_offers.ref_org = organisations.ref_org AND '.implode(' AND ', $cond));
    }


    print_r($query);
```

Comment: Ah I didn't see he was executing the query before adding to it, you're right.